# Not able to call REST based web-service using AJAX(simple javascript) in PhoneGap for IPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ajax, ios-simulator, cordova

Plz help,

I am simply calling the Rest Based Web-Service in my new PhoneGap App for Iphone.

I am using the XCode 3.2.3 in which I have installed the PhoneGap framework and it works fine.

Developed a simple javascript code which uses the AJAX. Below is the code.

THis code works fine the in:
IE, Morzilla and Safari Browser of my Mac Pc also on 
Safari browser of the Iphone Simulator but when I integrate this code in my PhoneGap app's `index.html` in www folder it doesn't give any response.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


    function callingRestBasedWebService()
    {

        alert('In callingRestBasedWebService');

        var username = document.getElementById('usernameid').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('passwordid').value;
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var responseXML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                alert("ResponseXML="+responseXML);

                if (window.DOMParser)   //Creating DOM Object for Morzilla  for parsing XML
                {
                    parser=new DOMParser();
                    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(responseXML,"text/xml");
                }
                else // Internet Explorer   // Creating DOM object for IE for parsing XML
                {
                    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async="false";
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(responseXML);
                }

                    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Login");
                    if(x[0].getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == 'Success')
                    {
                        alert('Login Successfull');

                    }else {
                        alert('Login Failed');
                    }


                }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://pc-a401115.patni.com:8080/BankWebService/resources/validateLogin?username="+username+"&password="+password,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }




</script>
</head>
<body>

<br><br>
Username : <input type="text" name="username" id="usernameid"><br><br>
Password :<input type="text" name="password" id="passwordid"><br><br>
<input type="button" name="Login" value="Login" onClick="javascript:callingRestBasedWebService();">
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me out, and plz inform if I am wrong some where..

Thanks,
MobileAppMaster

Comment: hey i was trying to call web services using this method but it was not working, used xui api. you ca see my  blog http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/02/callling-web-services-in.html

Answer (score 0):

since "pc-a401115.patni.com" has no dns record I suspect that your iphone can not resolve the hostname which should lead to a very long timeout (properly one minute with phonegap)

Try using the ip address of your webserver instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of phonegap, insert after head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.0.9.5.1.min.js">
</script>
```